# Filter between dates with AJAX, PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a problem when I try to implement a date filter:

My database is something like this:

```
start_date  |  end_date
2000        |  2005
```

My PHP select looks like this:

```
if (empty($processo) && empty($ano)){
                        $pegaSonda = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM sonda WHERE `modelo` = ?");
                        $pegaSonda->execute();
                    } else if(!empty($processo) && empty($ano)) {
                        $pegaSonda = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM sonda WHERE n_processo = '$processo'");
                        $pegaSonda->execute();
                    } else if(!empty($processo) && !empty($ano)){
                        //AQUI EU POSSO COLOCAR O FILTRO POR ANO
                        $pegaSonda = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM sonda WHERE n_processo = '$processo'");
                        $pegaSonda->execute();
                    }
```

The variable $ano (this is the year that the user will write in a input text and the ajax will send to PHP as Post request).

How can I use the `SELECT` when the user types the year?

The code I've tried looks like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM sonda WHERE n_processo = '$processo' AND start_date >= '$ano' OR end_date <= '$ano'"
```

Any help please?
Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: @NathanTuggy hi mate, i just edited it, to be honest i'm learning this, so i don't really know if the SELECT with dates is correct or i'm using it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer that we have reached after discussion

```
'$ano' BETWEEN start_date AND IF(end_date = '', YEAR(CURDATE()), end_date)
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your code, but i'm not sure if it is not working because the amount of conditions in my SELECT: `"SELECT * FROM sonda WHERE n_processo = '$processo' AND start_date <= '$ano' AND '$ano' <= end_date"`

Comment: @WilliamXavier if you need between use BETWEEN operator https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: I think i can't use BETWEEN because i have 2 fields to compare right?

Comment: @WilliamXavier '$ano' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date

Comment: Great, it worked like a charm, it was not working before because sometimes the "end_date" field is empty, is there a way i can avoid this?

Comment: i tried it but didn't worked: `"SELECT * FROM `".$tabela."` WHERE `fabricante` = ? AND `modelo` = ? AND `n_processo` = ? AND CASE WHEN end_date IS NULL THEN start_date <= '$ano' ELSE '$ano' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date END"` , did i used it correctly?

Comment: @WilliamXavier maybe fim is empty string not is null ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82436/discussion-between-alexander-madyuskin-and-william-xavier).